# Is the Aqua Teen Hunger Force ever actually shown fighting?

Tags: aqua-teen-hunger-force

At the beginning of each episode, Frylock, Master Shake and Meatwad are shown fighting criminal robots, deep sea monsters, etc., but, *are there any accounts of them going on these adventures?*

Though I've not seen every episode, it does seem as if all episodes are set during their residing in that house, next to Carl, and not during their apparent crime fighting times.

Comment: The very first episode showed the team investigating a case (barely), but as far as crime fighting, no. Never. That isn't the point of the show.

Comment: @DustinDavis Ah, yes, the rabbit episode. *"That isn't the point of the show."* -- I wasn't aware there is an actual point to the show. Can you tell me what it is? Thanks.

Comment: haha, there is no point to the show, but if there was one, it wouldn't be about what the intro portrays. It's just about them living together and their "misadventures".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In early episodes, the trio were identified by Master Shake as the "Aqua Teen Hunger Force", which solved crimes for money. After a few episodes, this premise and the use of the name by the characters were dropped. The premise was a trick that had been added to appease Cartoon Network executives, who "didn't want to air a show about food just going around and doing random things". In the show itself, Frylock mentions that they stopped fighting crime because "that wasn't making us a whole lot of money".

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqua_Teen_Hunger_Force)